# Calculating multilabel recall for this problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, precision-recall

I have a table with two columns, and the two entries of a row show that they are related:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | A |
| b | B |
| a | C |
| c | A |
| b | D |

Here `a` is related to `A, C` and `b` to `B, D` and `c` to `A`, meaning the same entry in `col1` might have multiple labels in `col2` related. I trained a `Machine Learning` model to quantify the relationship between `Col1` and `Col2` by creating a vector embedding of `Col1` and `Col2` and optimizing the `cosine_similarity` between the two vectors. Now, I want to test my model by calculating `Recall` on a test set. I want to check if at various `recall@N`, what proportion of these positive relationships can be retrieved. Suppose I have normalized vector representation of all entries in each column, then I can calculate the cosine distance between them as :

```
cosine_distance = torch.mm(col1_feature, col2_feature.t())
```

which gives a matrix of distances between all pairs that can be formed between `col1` and `col2`.

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dist(a,A) | dist(a,B) | dist(a,C) | dist(a,A) | dist(a, D) |
| dist(b,A) | dist(b,B) | dist(b,C) | dist(b,A) | dist(b, D) |
| dist(a,A) | dist(a,B) | dist(a,C) | dist(a,A) | dist(a, D) |
| dist(c,A) | dist(c,B) | dist(c,C) | dist(c,A) | dist(c, D) |
| dist(b,A) | dist(b,B) | dist(b,C) | dist(b,A) | dist(b, D) |

I can then calculate which pairs have largest distance to calculate `recall@k`. My question is how can I make this efficient for a millions of rows. I found out this  module in pytorch: `torchmetrics.classification.MultilabelRecall`(https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/recall.html), that seems to be useful but for that I need to specify number of labels. In my case, I can have variable number of labels for each unique entry of `col1`. Any ideas?

Comment: can't you count the unique labels (easy with pandas or any dataframe lib) before using the MultiLabelRecall ?

Answer (score 0):

As [GuiGav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12267516/guigav) vaguely suggested: Count the unique labels before using `MultiLabelRecall`.

You can use `pandas` to do so. First off, let's define a pandas df with the two columns specified in your question: `df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ["a", "b", "a", "c", "b"], "Col2": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D"]})`.

Now we plainly count the # of unique labels in the second column via using [`nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
n_labels = df["Col2"].nunique()
```

Before using `MultilabelRecall`, we just gotta create a tensor of the predicted and true labels for each entry in the first column:

```
groups = df.groupby("Col1")["Col2"].apply(list)

predicted = torch.tensor(groups.values)

true = torch.tensor(df.groupby("Col1").apply(lambda x: x["Col2"].tolist()))
```

Finished! Now you can simply calculate the `recall@k` for the respective `k` values you need:

```
recall = MultilabelRecall(num_labels = n_labels)
print(recall.compute(predicted, true, k = 1))
```

*Note that using pandas for creating the predicted / true tensors may not be the most efficient implementation.*

Comment: `true` is a bit stuffed and I reckon there are ways to do this cleaner - was the most efficient implementation that came to mind. You basically iterate over the unique entries in the first column and retrieve the corresponding label in the second column. With this list of labels you create a tensor for that entry. NOTE: I edited it now to be more.. understandable :)